# Java Input through formatted file

Tags: java, parsing

I need to take input from the file of the format

2
(3,4) (5,6)
3
(6,5) (7,8)

where I want just the integer value to store in some variable ,I dont want brackets and commas so how do I get this using pattern-match?

Comment: do you know regular expression? that should be where you begin.

Comment: Which integer? The ones inside brackets?

Comment: all the integers the ones' outside as well as inside the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the String method split, which allows use of regular expressions. Here's some example code to run for each line of input from your file, assuming you have instantiated an instance variable named contents of type ArrayList<Integer>:

```
public void readLine(String line) {
    String delimiters = "[ ,()]+"; // regular expression
    String[] tokens = line.split(delimiters);
    for (String token : tokens) {
        try {
            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(token); // convert String to Integer
            contents.add(i);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

The split method creates a few extra (empty) tokens, which the try/catch eliminates. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` to remove any non-numeric characters and `Integer.valueOf(String)` to get an Integer.

Comment: but I want all all integers separately,store them in kind of array of integers

Comment: @Manas give an example of what output you expect from that sample input.

Comment: I want to perform other operations from these integers therefore I just want individual integer to be stored in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the integers directly from the file using [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and specify a delimiter using [`Scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29), where the delimiter would be a regular expression (`"[,() ]{1,}"` for example). The `Scanner` methods `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` can be used to read the integers.

Comment: can you help me with the pattern its like 2 in first line then (3,4) (5,6) in the next line then 3 in the next and last line has (6,5) (7,8).

Comment: hmjd - I tried with your way I could get integers within the bracket but not the ones outside the bracket( 2 in first line then (3,4) (5,6) in the next line then 3 in the next and last line has (6,5) (7,8)) In the above case I couldnt get 2 and 3